# Submit button, MVC3, VB

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, http-post

I am having trouble using the values that were selected from the dropdown list.  How would you reccommend passing the selected values from the view?

Ideally, we want to use the selected dropdown values to determine a query.  Any help is appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Post some code!  We have no idea what values you are using, how you are outputting them as html, etc...

Comment: do not add things like "MVC", or "VB" to you titles. That's what tags are for.

Answer (score 0):

I would include them in the view model and then pass the viewmodel back to the controller.

viewmodel

```
public class vm
{
 //your other viewmodel data

 public string? SelectedValue { get; set; }
 public SelectList forDropDownUse { get; set; }
}
```

view

```
@model namespace.vm
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
 @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedValue, forDropDownUse, " -- Select A Value -- ")
 <input type="Submit" value="submit model" />
}
```

and then in your post action just get the selected value from the posted model object

controller (sorry, this is in c#)

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult postedAction(vm model)
{
 //actions with other data in model
 string selectedValue = model.SelectedValue.Value;
 //work with selected value
 return RedirectToAction("SomeDisplayAction");
}
```

Converted to vb.net from http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/

```
<HttpPost> _
Public Function postedAction(model As vm) As ActionResult
 'actions with other data in model
 Dim selectedValue As String = model.SelectedValue.Value
 'work with selected value
 Return RedirectToAction("SomeDisplayAction")
End Function
```

Comment: How would I use the <httppost> method to do this?

Comment: Is there an HTTP post method in VB?  This is where I'm getting held up. Thanks!